# Check metadata of S3 objects with AWS SDK for Java 2.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I was not able to find a way to check the metadata fields of an S3 object such as the `Content-Type` or the `Cache-Control` with the [AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/).

With the AWS SDK for Java 1.x it was as easy as this:

s3Client.getObjectMetadata("myBucket", "myfile.doc");

But I cannot see the analogous method for the newest version of the API.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is to use `HeadObjectRequest` and `HeadObjectResponse`:

```
HeadObjectRequest headObjectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .key(key)
  .build();
```

And then:

```
HeadObjectResponse headObjectResponse = s3Client.headObject(headObjectRequest);

System.out.println("This is what I need: " + headObjectResponse.contentType());
```

Comment: Is there a way to access this data from the response of a GetObjectRequest? Having a hard time finding it in the docs / examples on AWS...

Comment: @andrhamm Use `GetObjectResponse metaInfo = object.response();`

Answer (score 1):

Also relevant, you can get additional metadata using  [`getObjectAttributes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObjectAttributes.html), which for AWS S3 Java 2.x SDK is used in place of `getObjectMetadata`.